# POST jQuery to IFTTT webhook

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send data from my form to an IFTTT webhook using jQuery and an ajax function.

My webhook is trigger, however, my values are not received by IFTTT. So there must be something wrong with (sending) my data part..

My script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{EVENT}/with/key/{KEY}",
      type: "POST",
      data: 'JSON.stringify({
        "value1":"HELLO"
      })',
      contentType: "application/json",
      complete: function() {
        alert("Success");
      }
    });
  });
}); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two issues:

1. You're sending a string of JavaScript, not a JSON string. If this request sent successfully, you'd be sending `JSON.stringify(...` down the wire. But it's not sending successfully because
2. you've set the `Content-Type` to `application/json`, which triggers a preflight OPTIONS request. jQuery asks IFTTT if it can send `application/json` data, and won't send it unless IFTTT says it's okay. IFTTT isn't responding with the right go-ahead header, so jQuery doesn't send the real request.

Fortunately, IFTTT accepts `value1` et al. as form variables as well, so sending that way works:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btn').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{EVENT}/with/key/{KEY}",
      type: "POST",
      data: {"value1":"HELLO"},
      complete: function(){alert("Success")}
    });
  });
});
```